# Complex mySql ordering

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with products.

Their id are like 12345 for mothers, and 12345_1, 12345_2, ... for childs.

I want to sort them in order to have the mother desc, but then the child asc :

```
12345
12345_1
12345_2
12345_3
12345_4
12344
12344_1
12344_2
12344_3
12344_4
12340
12340_1
12340_2
12340_3
12340_4
```

How can I construct my order by’s clause for that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to exact the parts before and after the underscore:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '_', 1) DESC, 
         IF(LOCATE('_', id), SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '_', -1), '') ASC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98f09/5)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your sample data set:

```
select your_column
from your_table
order by cast(substring_index(your_column,'_',1) as signed integer) desc, 
  your_column asc
```